# Storing and accessing an array of pointers to structs

Tags: c

I'm working through a use case where I want to have a *dynamic array* of pointers, that point to a struct of some type.

I'm noticing some strange behavior, and I'm hoping somebody can help clarify.

First, I'll share a **passing test** using a *static array* of pointers.

```c
TEST test_f_chunk_array(void) {
  f_chunk* first;
  f_chunk* second;

  test_f_chunk_array_setup(&first, &second);

  // just validating that the setup is working as expected.
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(1ul, (*first->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(5ul, (*second->first)->next->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(6ul, (*second->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");

  f_chunk* arr[2] = {NULL};
  arr[0] = first;
  arr[1] = second;

  // original pointers were not mutated, not surprising.
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(1ul, (*first->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(5ul, (*second->first)->next->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(6ul, (*second->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");

  f_chunk* first_chunk = arr[0];
  f_chunk* second_chunk = arr[1];

  // awesome, retrieval works as expected.
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(1ul, (*first_chunk->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(5ul, (*second_chunk->first)->next->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(6ul, (*second_chunk->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");

  PASS();
}
```

Now, for the **failing test** using a *dynamic array*, I'm noticing behavior that I don't quite understand.

```c
TEST test_f_chunk_dynamic_array(void) {
  f_chunk* first;
  f_chunk* second;

  test_f_chunk_array_setup(&first, &second);

  // just validating that the setup is working as expected.
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(1ul, (*first->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(5ul, (*second->first)->next->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(6ul, (*second->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");

  // using dynamic array.
  size_t size = 2;
  f_chunk** arr = malloc(size * sizeof(f_chunk*));

  arr[0] = first;
  arr[1] = second;

  /*
    sanity check, I wouldn't expect for the underlying struct to be mutated
    as the array would only assign a copy of the pointer value?  
  */
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(1ul, (*first->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  // ^^^^ segfaults.

  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(5ul, (*second->first)->next->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(6ul, (*second->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");

  f_chunk* first_chunk = arr[0];
  f_chunk* second_chunk = arr[1];

  // this doesn't work either.
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(1ul, (*first_chunk->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(5ul, (*second_chunk->first)->next->bytes->offset, "%zu");
  ASSERT_EQ_FMT(6ul, (*second_chunk->first)->bytes->offset, "%zu");

  PASS();
}
```

It's very clear that I'm missing something, but I'm unsure of what.  I thought that allocating space and storing a pointer address on it wouldn't mutate the struct that pointer points to.

**Edit**

Sharing the setup if it helps clarify.

```c
void test_f_chunk_array_setup(f_chunk** first, f_chunk** second) {
  f_bytes* first_bytes;
  f_bytes* second_bytes;
  f_bytes* third_bytes;
  f_bytes_new(&first_bytes, true, 1ul);
  f_bytes_new(&second_bytes, true, 5ul);
  f_bytes_new(&third_bytes, false, 6ul);


  f_bytes_node* first_node;
  f_bytes_node* second_node;
  f_bytes_node* third_node;
  f_bytes_node_new(&first_node, first_bytes);
  f_bytes_node_new(&second_node, second_bytes);
  f_bytes_node_new(&third_node, third_bytes);

  first_node->next = NULL;
  second_node->next = NULL;
  third_node->next = second_node;

  f_chunk* first_chunk;
  f_chunk* second_chunk;

  f_chunk_new(&first_chunk, 1, &first_node, &first_node);
  f_chunk_new(&second_chunk, 2, &third_node, &second_node);

  *first = first_chunk;
  *second = second_chunk;
}
```

**Second Edit**

Minimal reproducible example here: https://godbolt.org/z/6c8z7coYq

Comment: What is `f_chunk` defined to be?

Comment: Great question.  `f_chunk` is a struct containing 2 members of `f_some_linked_list**`.  However, wouldn't this be irrelevant since I'm only assigning a `copy` of the pointer to `f_chunk`?

Comment: "I thought that allocating space and storing a pointer address on it wouldn't mutate the struct that pointer points to." That's true unless you have undefined behavior. I strongly suspect that you have UB in the code you haven't shown, probably in `test_f_chunk_array_setup`.

Comment: Debugging questions should always include a [mcve].

Comment: @WeijunZhou I shared the setup.

Comment: @Fe2O3 is it semantically different? If not, I prefer the former. Thanks.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I'm making an `array` of `pointers`. right?  Your example is an `array` of `f_chunk`. It's different, no?

Comment: `f_chunk_new(&first_chunk, 1, &first_node, &first_node);` is very likely to be wrong. The only reason you want to pass `&first_node` instead of just `first_node` is that you want to modify `first_node` and then use the new `first_node` value later, but in the code you have shown it is not used at all afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @WeijunZhou, I actually do use those node refs later on in the program, just not in this test.  But it shouldn't matter eh? Is it undefined to store double pointers in a struct?

```typedef struct FChunk {
  int current;
  f_bytes_node** first;
  f_bytes_node** last;
} f_chunk;
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter. I have also considered that possibility and that's why I said "very likely" instead of "definitely". You should edit the definition into the question and at this stage I think we really need a MRE, as commented by user3386109, preferably with a link to sites like Compiler Explorer.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks - I'll try to through up an MRE.

Comment: OT: Minor point: `f_bytes_node_new()` should probably be setting `next` to NULL instead of leaving it to the caller to do...

Comment: Thanks @Fe2O3.  It does! I'll put up a MRE.

Comment: I read again and I doubt you are doing something like `f_chunk->f_bytes_node = &first_node`. If that is the case, it is UB. Please check again that you are indeed **modifying** `first_node` in `f_chunk_new` and then you need to use the **modified** value later. Otherwise the function signature is still not justified. Anyway, an MRE will help.

Comment: So I think i found a problem.  (I'm really sorry for the runaround; wasn't checking malloc result before).  It does appear to be failing to allocate.

https://godbolt.org/z/6c8z7coYq

Comment: @WeijunZhou super strange to me, as the setup function works in the first example but not the second.

Comment: As I said, `f_chunk->f_bytes_node = &first_node` (or in your Godbolt link, `init->first = firstref`) and then later trying to dereference the stored pointer is UB, and one possible manifestation of undefined behavior is that "it just works". By the way, you should replace the code in your question with the ones from the MRE. The question should be self-contained even without the link.

Comment: Thanks! I think that makes sense.  So the nodes are heap allocated, but the pointers to those nodes live on the stack? and I'm trying to take the address of those?  If you're up for formalizing an answer, I'd love to accept it.

Comment: > By the way, you should replace the code in your question with the ones from the MRE. The question should be self-contained even without the link.

Stackoverflow complains if I do that, so I won't.

Comment: That probably means your MRE is still too long. Anyway I'll write an answer explaining the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of revision 4 of the question,

This part of code at the end of a function

```
f_chunk_new(&first_chunk, 1, &first_node, &first_node);
f_chunk_new(&second_chunk, 2, &third_node, &second_node);

*first = first_chunk;
*second = second_chunk;
```

hints that there may be an issue with the prototype of `f_chunk_new`. From the godbolt link, The prototype of `f_chunk_new` is
`f_chunk_new(f_chunk** out, int current, f_some_struct_node** firstref, f_some_struct_node** lastref)`, where the third parameter is a double pointer and you are passing `&first_node` to it. This usually indicates that you want to modify `first_node` in the function and use the modified value later, which you don't.

Since `*firstref` is not modified at all in the function, there is no reason to take a pointer to non-const (in this case it's a double pointer, but that's irrelavant) as a parameter and then pass the address of a local variable to it. This is always a mistake.

The ultimate reason you are encountering this behavior is because you are storing the address of a local variable in your `f_chunk` struct, by essentially doing `first_chunk->first=&first_node` in `test_f_chunk_array_setup`. After `test_f_chunk_array_setup` returns, the lifetime of variable `first_node` ends and now you have a dangling pointer in your struct. Later when you do `*first_chunk->first` in your test function, you are accessing a variable whose lifetime has already ended, which is undefined behavior. That `test_f_chunk_array` seems to work and `test_f_chunk_dynamic_array` does not is purely coincidental and you have undefined behavior in both.

The C standard does not intrinsically have the concepts of stacks and heaps but if it helps you understand it better then yes your comment is correct, the nodes are heap allocated, but the pointer is still a stack variable and storing the address of a stack variable for later use is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful write-up! That makes a lot of sense.  I was storing the double pointer in order to collect some linked lists in an array async and reduce them by modifying their tails to point at each other.  It sounds likely that I don't actually need to store their pointers though, so i'll try another route.

Appreciate you!